# when i tried npm start this error happens

Tags: node.js, git, npm

im using this : https://github.com/SomnathDas/Whatsapp-Botto-Re
is that a problem in npm installation or its the problem with previous files?
and im beginner so pls help me out

```
$ npm start
    > whatsapp-botto-re@3.0.1 start E:\git bashh\TEST\whatsapp-botto-Re
    > node index.js
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
      throw err;
      ^
    
    Error: Cannot find module '@open-wa/wa-automate'
    Require stack:
    - E:\git bashh\TEST\whatsapp-botto-Re\index.js
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (E:\git bashh\TEST\whatsapp-botto-Re\index.js:1:20)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
        at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) {
      code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
      requireStack: [ 'E:\\git bashh\\TEST\\whatsapp-botto-Re\\index.js' ]
    }
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! whatsapp-botto-re@3.0.1 start: `node index.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the whatsapp-botto-re@3.0.1 start script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\Bilal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-19T12_24_18_581Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Hi, have you run `npm install` before `npm start`?

Answer (score 2):

Try executing `npm install` in the console. The errors are because there are dependencies that are not installed yet. A hint is given in the error message:

> ```
> npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
> ```

Answer (score 0):

After cloning the project. Execute this command in the project directory:

`npm install`

this will install all the dependencies.

And after it try running it.